# Setting Default Font in Emacs 26.1

Tags: init-file, fonts

I want to set a default font in my Emacs (version 26.1, running on Arch, using Xmonad). I have tried various options in my init.el file (under .emacs.d). None seemed to work or persist when I restarted X.

The only thing that works and persists is specifying it in my .Xresources file, e.g. in my case Emacs.font: DejaVuSansMono-14

Is there a "standard" way of setting the default font in Emacs ? Is this it ? Is it dependent on the emacs version, i.e. this is the latest version 26.1

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,

Roy.

Comment: Did you try setting the frame parameters using the `default-frame-alist` or the `initial-frame-alist`?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Parameters.html

Comment: Yes, but I will double check. If these are in init.el, do you not have anything in .Xresources ?

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
(set-frame-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-14" nil t)
```

to your init.el file. This would affect **all** frames (last parameter `t`).

If you're not sure about the font name, you can see a list of all available fonts by evaluating this

```
(message
    (mapconcat (quote identity)
        (sort (font-family-list) #'string-lessp) "\n"))
```

in your `*scratch*` buffer. Check the output in your `*Messages*` buffer.

Other tips [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/93htxs/setting_a_font_in_emacs/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your init.el file and change the font family and height to whatever you want.

```
(defun my/setup-frame (&optional frame)
  "Configure look of FRAME.

If FRAME is nil, configure current frame. If non-nil, make FRAME
current."
  (when frame (select-frame frame))
  (when (window-system)
    (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 125 :family "Fira Mono")))

(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'my/setup-frame)
  (my/setup-frame))
```

Comment: [Stefan recommends `face-spec-set`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00602.html), although it seems [it might fail regardless due to some race condition](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00735.html).

Comment: Works like a charm but rather than specifying :height and :family I find it more convenient to use :font as in (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Terminus 16").